# Problems in iteratively reading different length files with pandas.read_csv(): outputting same length lists

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

in my code I take the datasets from the folder and read them iteratively. The files are in the format txt. I use the function read_csv() to perform the task:

```
        for product, rca in zip(self.products_list, self.rca_list):
            prod = pd.read_csv(Path(f"data/{product}"), header=None, dtype=str)
            self.products_code_list[product.replace("products", "").replace(".txt", "")] = prod
```

So, what's the matter? The original files are of different lengths but when I look at the output lists as you can see they are all of the same lengths:

```
for product in aggregator.products_list:
    print(aggregator.prod)
```

gives me back:

```
        0
0     0101
1     0102
2     0103
3     0104
4     0105
...    ...
1211  9905
1212  9919
1213  9930
1214  9931
1215  9950

[1216 rows x 1 columns]
         0
0     0101
1     0102
2     0103
3     0104
4     0105
...    ...
1211  9905
1212  9919
1213  9930
1214  9931
1215  9950

[1216 rows x 1 columns] 

...
```

I add relevant info: 1216 is the length of the last year present in self.products_list from which I am iteratively taking the names of the datasets to be read.

What could be the problem? I am struggling to figure it out.

Comment: Your `for` loop is not changing `self.products_list`.  It's changing `self.products_code_list`.  Right?

Comment: Exactly, `self.products_list` is a list of all the names of files containing the products' code for every year in the folder: 
`['products1995.txt', 'products1996.txt', ..., 'products2016.txt', 'products2017.txt']`.

Instead, `self.products_code_list` contains the list of the codes associated to every year (iteratively given by the `for` cycle).

Comment: OK, but in your question you said you were looking at the "output lists", but your loop is printing `products_list`, and that's an INPUT, not an output.  How are you creating `products_list`?  Show us that.